# hibernate update hql over large set of rows

Tags: hibernate, session, hql

I have an hibernate HQL (oracle 10g) thats like this

```
update table1 set modified_timestamp=systimestamp where id = :id
```

This query needs to be executed for each row in `table1` as timestamp is later used for picking up records.

When I execute this as named query, the performance degrades with processing time. I cannot do a blind `session.clear()` as there other objects in session that need to be modified further.

Can anyone suggest how best to solve this performance degradation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually created a Stored Proc at the end of transaction that would update timestamps of the records belonging to the transaction

Answer (score 0):

With the method:

```
session.evic(entity);
```

can unlink session entity that interests you.

Regards,